# Cannot utilize code from Cocoapod I created

Tags: swift, github, cocoapods

I created a cocoa pods Pod (my first one), https://github.com/Evilsmaher/DepthCamera, and I have published it (so feel free to reference this if you'd like). My problem is I cannot access the code from it.

**Steps I have taken:**

1) Make sure that the pod is accessible.

-- I know this is true because I can do `import DepthCamera` and I don't receive errors. I can also see that the header 
[image: Pod Header]
so I know that I can access the code.

-- Set code to public. In my file `RealTimeDepthViewController` accessible [here](https://github.com/Evilsmaher/DepthCamera/blob/master/Camera/RealTimeDepthViewController.swift).

**Problem:**

Cannot access code. When I call the initializer I get this error `Use of unresolved identifier 'RealTimeDepthViewController'`, also seen below. 
[image: Error]

**Question:**

How can I access code from the pod -- i.e., the whole reason for creating the pod.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid error. Will address here even though it feels foolish.

The init method was `public init` but the class was `class RealTimeDepthViewController`. Swift default access is internal and the `init` method and a couple others need to be `public` but so does the class. So it needed to be `public class RealTimeDepthViewController`.